# it's possible remove splash Screen on flutter app for android and ios

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-test, flutter-android

Please help, I am working on an application using flutter technology, and I want to remove the splash screen default and i preferred use custom splash screen that's allow me to build whole page . so , am trying to remove default splash from android and ios

Comment: Can you share what the default Splash Screen looks like for you?

Answer (score 1):

There are instructions for how to change the default screen [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-2019-real-splash-screens-tutorial-16078660c7a1).
Although these are the default screens that cannot be overridden in a flutter. Any splash screen widget will show a default splash screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I must make sure of that